# FileReader is already defined in this compilation unit error Java

Tags: java, dijkstra

So I'm working on reading in a ".txt" file to use it to implement Dijkstra's algorithm, but every time I try to compile it gives me a "FileReader is already defined in this compilation unit" error while highlighting where I imported it in the beginning. If I take this out, however, it throws a constructor error when I'm trying to read in the file that it's of the wrong type. What am I missing here??

Here is my code:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
//import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class FileReader
{
    public ArrayList main1()
    {
        System.out.println("got here");
        try
        {
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File("input1.txt")));
```

I can provide more if needed, but this is where all of the errors crop up.

Comment: Well yes, you're declaring a class called `FileReader` as well as importing a type called `FileReader`. I would strongly encourage you to change the name of your class.

Comment: Your main class is named `FileReader`. Rename it.

Comment: Try to rename your main class to something else `public class FileReader`, maybe `public class Test`

Comment: Ok, yea. That was dumb of me. Thank you!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your class is named the same as FileReader in the java.io package (you have commented out above). Rename your class to something else like TextFileReader or InputFileReader or use the fully qualified class name for java.io.FileReader.

Answer (score 0):

Just rename your class "FileReader" to different toxicity, in order not to be confused.